# Simple CRUD app, I need help in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, crud, dbcontext

I finished my simple CRUD MVC web app, it works great, but my teacher said the controller is simple code and I need to fix it. He mentioned the context but I didn't understand him.

I would upload images of my code if anyone can help me, I am a big beginner.

```
using GasStation.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GasStation.Controllers

{
    public class HomeController : Controller

    {
        public ActionResult Index(
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetOrders()
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var orders = dc.Orders.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName).ToList();

                return Json(new { data = orders },
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult Save(int id)
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {

    var v = dc.Orders.Where(a => a.OrderID == id).FirstOrDefault();

                return View(v);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Save(Order emp)
        {
            bool status = false;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    if (emp.OrderID > 0)
                    {
                        var v = dc.Orders.Where(a => a.OrderID == 
emp.OrderID).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (v != null)
                        {
                            v.FirstName = emp.FirstName;
                            v.LastName = emp.LastName;
                            v.FuelType = emp.FuelType;
                            v.Quantity = emp.Quantity;
                            v.City = emp.City;
                            v.Address = emp.Address;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dc.Orders.Add(emp);
                    }

                    dc.SaveChanges();

                    status = true;
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }

        [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult Delete (int id)
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var v = dc.Orders.Where(a => a.OrderID == 
id).FirstOrDefault();

                if (v != null)
                {
                    return View(v);
                }
                else
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]

        [ActionName("Delete")]

        public ActionResult DeleteOrder(int id)
        {
            bool status = false;

            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var v = dc.Orders.Where(a => a.OrderID == 
id).FirstOrDefault();

                if (v != null)
                {
                    dc.Orders.Remove(v);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    status = true;
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should get more details, but perhaps he means for you to use dependency injection? That is a more advanced concept. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632269.aspx

Comment: Yes he means that, i hope i find good tutorials that can help.